# Postgres Group by json array column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I'm having a hard time understanding Postgres json array type. How to do a group by using json array column. For example:

```
select product, avg(sales)
from Order 
group by product
```

> "Error: could not identify an equality operator for type json"

```
--Order--
id | sales | product                 
1  | 36    | ["874746", "474657"] 
2  | 120   | ["874748"] 
3  | 15    | ["874736", "474654"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `jsonb` (binary) 9.4+:

```
select product::jsonb, avg(sales)
from Order 
group by product::jsonb
```